# How to make IntelliJ IDEA's Auto Pop-Up Documentation appear every time?

Tags: java, autocomplete, intellij-idea, code-completion

In IntelliJ IDEA, if you type a variable and then hit the period "." button, you get a list of possible members to choose from. If you press Ctrl+Space, you get a documentation window containing further explanations of each member.

As a learner, **I want to make this extended documentation pop-up automatically every time**. For example, if I'm programming in Java and I type:

```
System.
```

I want the documentation window to pop-up every time I select a member, without having to press Ctrl+Space. If you've used Visual Studio to program in C# I think you'll know what I mean.

Going into File->Settings->Editor->Code Completion and changing the autopopup documentation timers did not help.

Visual Studio 2010 implements intellisense extremely well, in my opinion.

Comment: Can anybody explain how can i disable it ?  Its quite annoying at times.

Comment: the new version is support this
please see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530329/intellij-13-auto-doc-pop-up-on-mouseover-solution-doesnt-work-anymore

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Automatic documentation pop-up was designed to work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> code completion, otherwise you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to invoke it.

It is not displayed with the new fully automatic code completion introduced in the latest IntelliJ IDEA version, this behavior is by design.

Comment: Got it, thanks. It would be nice if there was an option to make it display automatically without pressing Ctrl+Space or Ctrl+Q. I mean, giving the *option* can't hurt, especially for learners like me. And I think even experts would accidentally learn something.

I wonder if there is some plugin to do this.

Comment: What is the difference between Ctrl+Space and Ctrl+Q?

Comment: Ctrl+Space is code completion shortcut, Ctrl+Q is Quick JavaDoc shortcut. Code completion can work automatically without Ctrl+Space and manually when you press the shortcut, JavaDoc can pop-up on manual code completion automatically or manually when you press Ctrl+Q, see http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Completion+features for advanced list of code completion features.