# Intellij 13 Auto doc pop up on mouseover solution doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, javadoc, jetbrains-ide

I have been using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615516/intellij-tooltip-shows-javadocs) for IntelliJ 12 for auto popup quick documentation on mouse over.

But the new version of IntelliJ 13 does not do anything when you set the `auto.show.quick.doc=true` in the `idea.properties` file.

Any Ideas to get this to work for version JetBrains IntelliJ 13?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For **ItelliJ IDEA 13** the setting `auto.show.quick.doc=true` property in the `idea.properties` appears to now reside in the preferences.

Go to the ItelliJ IDEA Menu -> **Preferences** -> **Editor** -> scroll down to the **Other** section and **Check** *Show quick doc on mouse move*

[image: IntelliJ Preferences]

Now you have mouse over Quick Doc functionality working again for **ItelliJ IDEA 13**:

[image: Show quick doc on mouse move]

Comment: Also, you can find my blog post regarding this issue [**here**](http://blog.iteedee.com/2013/12/intellij-13-quick-doc-pop-up-on-mouseover/)

Comment: thank god, this was so annoying, now i know how to turn it off, this didnt show correct documentation and was always empty and super annoying, probably because i am behind proxy or intellij 14/15 is buggy as hell

Comment: Worth noting: not sure if this ever happened to anyone else, but IntelliJ IDEA seems to hang sometimes when fetching online documentation. Each time I hovered on a specific nodejs module method (`async.series`) it froze up on the popup. By unchecking the quick doc feature, I can be productive again!